# Which user action causes a click event

Tags: android, smartphone

A click event on a desktop is normally generated, when the user clicks with a mouse. But you dont use a mouse with a smartphone.

So far I didnt find way to generate a click event on my touchscreen. Are there certain hardware features, whith which you can "click"?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't get UI click events when user on Android phone clicks "desktop" (home screen). You only get click events when user clicks something in your app.

Taken from [Handling UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) tutorial:

```
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
    ...
    // Capture our button from layout
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.corky);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    button.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);
    ...
}
```